# Obtain the pdf file path from a website after being execute from a Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, pdf

So I am trying to figure out a way when users open a pdf file from a website then have a Delphi application to execute and show the pdf. Is it possible to somehow copy the url location where the file originated from and pass it to a string when the form is created.

Comment: If the URL is available in the browser, then that means the browser is *already* showing the PDF. Why would your program run in that case? It seems what you really want is for the browser to download the PDF and *not* display it, instead using your program to open the downloaded file, it might with Acrobat Reader. So your problem is not how to detect the browser's PDF URL, but rather how to tell any supported browser to invoke your program for PDFs instead of displaying them internally.

Comment: Remy knows what I am trying to achieve. I only want to the url path.

Answer (score 3):

A browser downloads the PDF to a temp file before then launching an external app to display that temp file (if not displayed inside the browser itself).  If that app happens to be your Delphi app, it will only be told (via command line parameter) about the temp file, not the URL where the PDF originally came from.

Depending on which browser you are using, and what APIs it exposes, you *might* be able to query the browser's cache folder looking for the URL that maps to the temp file.

For example, Internet Explorer uses [WinInet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx) internally, and WinInet exposes a [Caching API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383928.aspx) for working with IE's cache data.  You can use [`FindFirstUrlCacheEntry()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384026.aspx) and [`FindNextUrlCacheEntry()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384049.aspx) to enumerate the contents of the cache, where the [`INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385134.aspx) structure has a `lpszSourceUrlName` field for the URL and a `lpszLocalFileName` field for the local filename in the cache.  You can use [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_InternetCache)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) to get the path of the cache itself.

Comment: You should also mention that this would only work when server serves the PDF as a file through HTTP protocol (URL to the file is available). But it won't work when PDF is transferred with the use of data stream in which case there is no URL available.